# How to ensure all the cron jobs have done?

Tags: logging

Suppose we should run a cron job every minute, how can we know that all the cron jobs have run in the past time? There will be missing cron jobs in some situations, such as the server down or stop the cron jobs sometime for maintainning.

Answer (score 0):

Use log to ensure this.

1. Set a `start_time` for cron jobs
2. After each cron job has done, add the time of the cron job to a set `done_cron_job_set`
3. Regularly, we can get `all_cron_job_set` according to `now` and the `start_time`. Then the `missing_cron_job_set` = `all_cron_job_time_set -`
   done_cron_job_time_set`

But there are some problems.

1. If we record every cron job, there will be 520000+ records every year
2. How often should we check the missing cron jobs? Should we check all the records from the start time or just check part of them?
3. Should we delete or merge the logs? Such as `2017-01-01's` records is complete, can we use `2017-01-01: true` to replace all the records in `2017-01-01`